# Linux SystemRescueCD, eth1 works but not eth0

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, gentoo, rescue-disk

Got a RHEL system that I'm trying to troubleshoot. I used the Linux SystemRescueCD (Gentoo Linux). When I boot, I choose option 1 ("default boot options"). If I boot and just configure eth1, I can ping my gateway. However, when I configure eth0, I cannot.

The first time I tried I configured eth0, but somehow eth1 existed when I checked ifconfig -a. However, when I rebooted and only configured eth1, there was no eth0.

The list of commands that can be ran is extremely limited. I've never heard of eth0 failing while eth1 works. Googling it seems to lead to no help. Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The connection is only going to work if you have a network connection.  My guess is you only have one network wire plugged into one port.  Keep in mind RHEL can detect your interfaces in a different order then the rescue CD.  So eth0 under rhel might be eth1 under GENTO which can cause confusion.

If you try to configure eth0 and get an error it could help figure out what is wrong.